# Parsing an xml list, null error

Tags: c#, xml

```
<items>
  <item id="2" value="100"/>
  <item id="3" value="50"/>
</items>
```

I want to put this into `List<Item>`, where `Item` is a class with `Id` and `Value` properties.

However the following code:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"itemsdata.xml");
List<Item> items= xmlDoc.Descendants("items").Select(x => new Transfer()
{
    FromId = (uint) x.Element("id"),
    Amount = (uint) x.Element("value")
}).ToList();
```

Throws the following exception:

> "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: element"

Answer (score 2):

You probably should be searching for the `"item"` descendants (and not the `"items"` descendants) and then query for the respective **attributes**:

```
List<Item> items = xmlDoc.Descendants("item").Select(x => new Item()
{
    FromId = (uint) x.Attribute("id"),
    Amount = (uint) x.Attribute("value")
}).ToList();
```